# RTSP stream: Possible ways to display in browser with everchanging stream-timestamp-depending overlay image?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, stream

The scenario is as follows:

- I receive RTSP stream
- Every second I receive a bunch of additional data corresponding to the exact timestamp of the stream
- The stream needs to be displayed in the web browser. For each new portion of data new overlay image needs to be shown, in the exactly correct timestamp of the stream.
- The stream needs to be saved for the VOD functionality.

It seems RTSP is not natively supported even in HTML5. I'm thinking about the following implementation:

1. Receive RTSP and data on .NET server
2. Each second compose a 1 second chunk of the video
3. Save this chunk into the DB along with the coresponding data
4. Send this chunk and the data to the web browser
5. Use JS to play this chunk and draw an overlay

I currently don't know how to implement #2 and #5. Are there any (C#?) libraries to discretize the stream? And, are there any JS libraries that may play chunks we compose at #2? I'm a complete newbie when it comes to video processing, so any directions would be appreciated.